# Create table syntax not working in hsql

Tags: java, hsqldb, create-table

I am new to hsqldb. I am developing simple application to get the some input from user. So Searched for embedded database and found hsqldb is the solution for my requirement.

I have some create table syntax but it throws exception.

(This Query executed by using Netbeans Database services)

Query :

```
CREATE TABLE  company (
  comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  comp_id int(40) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (comp_id)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE  company (
  comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  comp_id int(40) NOT NULL IDENTITY
);
```

hsql db throws the error :

```
Error code -5581, SQL state 42581: unexpected token: ( : line: 3
Line 2, column 1

Execution finished after 0 s, 1 error(s) occurred.
```

Kindly help me out..

Thanks in Advance..

Cheers...!

Comment: I have used the below query for my requirement.              **CREATE TABLE  company (
   comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   comp_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(start with 1)
 );**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `INT or INTEGER` **without specify the field length** as it is not required for Int type fields. It is required for `VARCHAR` and `DECIMAL`etc. type fields.

```
 CREATE TABLE  company (
   comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   comp_id int
 );
```

To auto increment:

```
 ALTER TABLE company ALTER COLUMN comp_id 
 SET GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);
```

Alternatively:

```
 CREATE TABLE  company (
   comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   comp_id int GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY 
                                         (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL
 );
```

You may also add the PRIMARY_KEY as below:

```
 CREATE TABLE  company (
   comp_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   comp_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (comp_id)
 );
```

Comment: Thanks.. If i execute the first query works fine. But the second query throw the exception **Error code -5532, SQL state 42532: primary key already exist
Line 1, column 2**

Comment: @DhinaKaran: `IDENTITY` keyword makes it for you. **I think you are fine with the first query itself**, otherwise try the updated second query.

Comment: Ya. Its working But still I have a problem with insert query **INSERT INTO company (comp_name) VALUES('ABC');** says **Error code -10, SQL state 23502: integrity constraint violation: NOT NULL check constraint; SYS_CT_17649 table: COMPANY column: COMP_ID**

Comment: For Query 1 : **Error code -5581, SQL state 42581: unexpected token: ( : line: 3**

Comment: @DhinaKaran Try putting `NOT NULL` in the end and use GENERATED BY DEFAULT.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19004/discussion-between-dhina-karan-and-yogendra-singh)