# Spring boot error: NULL not allowed for column "ID" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I keep getting this error on start up of my Spring Boot Application

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "ID"; SQL statement:
insert into bookings(bookings_name) values('Kris') [23502-199]
```

data.sql has

```
insert into bookings(bookings_name) values('Kris');
insert into bookings(bookings_name) values('Martin');
```

And I believe I have the annotations so that @Id is generated automatically

```
@Entity
class Bookings {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    private String BookingsName;

    public Long  getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getBookingsName() {
        return BookingsName;
    }

    public Bookings(String BookingsName) {
        super();
        this.BookingsName = BookingsName;

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookings [id=" + id + ", BookingsName=" + BookingsName + "]";
    }

}
```

I am just starting to learn Spring boot and every example I find online doesn't seem to transalte to my very trivial example here.

---

Full Application.java

```
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}


@Component
class BookingsCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {



    }

}




interface BookingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Bookings, Long> {

    Collection<Bookings> findByBookingsName(String BookingsName);

}


@RestController
class BookingsRestController {

    @Autowired
    BookingsRepository BookingsRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/Bookingss")
    Collection<Bookings> Bookingss() {
        return this.BookingsRepository.findAll();

    }

}


@Entity
class Bookings {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    private String BookingsName;

    public Long  getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getBookingsName() {
        return BookingsName;
    }

    public Bookings(String BookingsName) {
        super();
        this.BookingsName = BookingsName;

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bookings [id=" + id + ", BookingsName=" + BookingsName + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: How was the table created?

Comment: Here's a similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094773/7736617

Answer (score 2):

Which database do you use ? I think that the default strategy may not always work.
Try to use a different strategy in your entity declaration :

```
@Entity
class Bookings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter your database so that the ID column is an identity/auto-increment column i.e. the value will be managed by H2 and clients will not specify a value for new records.

Once you have done this then the the records in data.sql should be loaded without any issues.

[auto increment ID in H2 database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353167/1356423)

For the JPA entities you need to update as below to advise your JPA provider that IDs are manged by the database:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a confusion here about Spring/JPA and DBMS ID generation. Running pure SQL to your database (through java code or not) like hardcoded "insert into bookings(bookings_name) values('Kris');" will not care about the Id field of the entity being annotated @GeneratedValue or not.

To insert the bookings you could :

- Use the JPA way to insert data through EntityManager
- configure your DBMS schema to generate default IDs
- Use IDs in the insert statement of your SQL

Hope that could help,

bye